# Integrating JIRA with StarTeam

Tags: version-control, jira, starteam, jira-plugin

Are there any options for integrating [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) with [Borland's StarTeam](http://www.borland.com/products/starteam/) for Source Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no officially supported integration for StarTeam and JIRA.

This may be made possible by a StarTeam plugin for JIRA in the future or by creating a custom JIRA plugin. Further information may be found on the JIRA website at: http://jira.atlassian.com/